# How to improve my delete statement in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, sql-delete

If I have a 3(inst, acct and recordno) columns as part of primary key and I knew only values of first 2,and my table has multiple indexes and every index has first 2 columns (inst and acct) and third one is something different.

Now questions.

1. if I have the delete query like this `Delete from TABL where inst=XXX and acct=123456789` which key it will pick up?
2. Is it fine if I add an extra `where` condition like `recordno > 0`.

Comment: For #1, Oracle might not even use an index at all, depending on cardinality and the number of records being deleted.  If deleting a large number of records, or if the table be very small, it might not use any index.  For #2, assuming it does use an index, I would expect it to use `(inst, acct, recordno)`.

Comment: Following up on Tim's comment, the optimizer changes between different versions of Oracle, and the optimizer might choose different execution plans for that same query on different days - it depends on your data, the version you're running, etc. The only way to know for sure is to get the execution plan from the database.

Adding the extra condition is fine, but I would caution against adding additional SQL if the command already works as expected. At best, it does nothing and won't impact performance. At worst, it will change the execution plan and cause detrimental performance.

Comment: Since the choice is between indexes that all have the same two leading columns, if the Optimizer is smart (which it is, in all cases I have seen), if it does choose to use an index at all, it will choose the one with the shortest keys - so that it reads as little from disk as possible. Suppose you have two indexes, both on three columns. The first two are the ones you mentioned. For one index, the third column is a date; for the other index, a `varchar2(4000)` that does, indeed, have very long text in each row. I bet the Optimizer will choose the first index over the second every time.

Comment: By *"which key will it pick up"* do you mean *"which index will it use"* ? In any case, tuning a `delete` is exactly the same as tuning a `select`. The optimiser will use the execution plan with the lowest computed cost.

Comment: If i add "recordno > 0" does it have any negative impact on performance? 
Why i am asking is because,  if my query is like "Delete from TABL where inst=XXX and acct=123456789" then it will delete all the reocrds having these 2 values, 
but if i add any 3rd column so, it will check for whether the column value is as mentioned and then record will be deleted. So, it may impact the performance.

Note: In both the cases output of explain plan is same.

Comment: If the explain plan and cost is the same, it will have no impact on performance.